# Ionic won't build if --prod specificed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I wanted to build out the web version of my application and fired off the Ionic build --prod command after adding the browser platform.

My Output:

```
> ionic build --prod
Running app-scripts build: --prod
[09:32:57]  build prod started ...
[09:32:57]  clean started ...
[09:32:57]  clean finished in 58 ms
[09:32:57]  copy started ...
[09:32:58]  deeplinks started ...
[09:32:58]  deeplinks finished in 164 ms
[09:32:58]  ngc started ...
[09:33:14]  ngc finished in 16.15 s
[09:33:14]  preprocess started ...
[09:33:14]  preprocess finished in 4 ms
[09:33:14]  webpack started ...
[09:33:14]  copy finished in 16.98 s
```

I've let the process sit for at least an hour, but it never progresses. I don't get any error messages, but it never progresses. Any idea how I can get the project to build?

I'm using Ionic CLI 3.20.0 and Angular 5.2.10.

Comment: Check your RAM. if Node.js consuming all your RAM.

Comment: I have about 6 Gb free. Was surprised to see it's using about 600Mb of memory.

Comment: Ionic is not working with just about any version of Angular. You should refer to the documentation to learn what specific versions of Ionic works with what specific version of Angular (that it was well tested with). Using any other than recommended versions can cause snowflake effects that you would want ot avoid.

Comment: Is 5.2.10 not supported? It's what came from the Ionic-Cli.I haven't upgraded it

Comment: I have tested it, it works. Initially it freezed in ` copy finished in 16.98 s` but after little time progress went

Answer (score 0):

To run or build you have to use

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --release
```

## or

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

and please refer to the documentation also  https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/

Comment: tried ionic cordova build browser --prod --release . Hangs at exactly the same spot.